# ArcGIS- Band collection statistics tool correlation less than -1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, correlation

I am trying to work out the correlation coefficient using band collection statistics in ArcGIS 10 between 2 rasters (a sea surface temperature raster and a storm genesis density raster created using point density tool).

However it is giving me a correlation coefficient of less than -1 which is not possible (as stated on the band collection tool help page)?

Any ideas on why I'm getting this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason could be different data types. I would check data types for each rasters and also convert them as floats.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I converted both to floats (using raster to float tool) and that has solved the issue. Many thanks